# Elements doesnot hold values after executing javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, element

I am having two button click events. One is by javascript another is written in vb. the first button(javascript) is for getting all values through some controls like textbox, dropdownlists. second one(vb) is for saving them into sql. Except the Save button, all control's postback is false. now the problem is, on the second event, even all controls' values changed they keep the initial values when the page loaded first itself. I feel this is because the page did not get the postback.

sample code(javascript),

```
function btnget_click()
{
    if(ddlccy.options[ddlccy.selectedIndex].value == "C1")   //here ddlccy value is "c1" but the initial value on load is 'c17'
       {
        bmd = dsrt[0];
        hbmd.value=dsrt[1];
       }
}
```

vb:

```
Private Sub txtpper1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtpper1.TextChanged
   If ddlccy.SelectedValue = "C1" Or ddlccy.SelectedValue = "C5" Or ddlccy.SelectedValue = "C6" Or ddlccy.SelectedValue = "C12" Then  'ddlccy shows 'c17' and codition goes to else
       'some code
   Else
       txtpfig.Text = Round(CDec(hbmd.Value) / CDec(txtpfig1.Text), Session("ratedis"))        
   End IF
End Sub
```

I think you guys understood what is the problem. Is there any way to hold the controls' values worked out through javascript?

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to target newer browsers, you can save values using [`Session Storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage).

Failing that, you can copy values into a `hidden` input and send them back down as part of the HTML.  It's ugly, but anything dealing with webforms is ugly...